# How to generate combinations of r elements in a given array of size n in swift?

Tags: swift, permutation

I want total permutation pairs and its count
Like.
If input array is {1, 2, 3, 4} and r is 2.
then output should be {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4} and {3, 4}.

Comment: And you tried what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the *total permutation pairs* are

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3]]
```

There's no need to reinvent the wheel. Apple provides a collection of useful and optimized algorithms.

Add the package [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) to your project

Then write

```
import Algorithms

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    
let permutations = array.permutations(ofCount: 2)
print(Array(permutations), permutations.count)
```